# dplyr mutating multiple columns using two columns as arguments to custom function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(10, 20, 30, 20), 
      B=c(0, 10, 20, 10), 
      C=c(11, 22, 21, 12),
      D=c(13, 11, 33, 15))

 A  B  C  D
10  0 11 13
20 10 22 11
30 20 21 33
20 10 12 15
```

and a function to get the index of the number in a pair closest to a number of interest:

```
comp <- function(x, y) {
    # x = number of interest, y = vector of 2 numbers for comparison)
    ind <- which(abs(y-x)==min(abs(y-x)))
    if (length(ind)==2) {
        ind <- 3
    }
    return(ind)
}
```

(The if statement is for when the number is smack in the middle of the two numbers, ex. 15 compared to 10 and 20).

I would like to change columns C & D to the index for which the number is closest using my function (1 for A or 2 for B):

```
 A  B  C  D
10  0  1  1
20 10  1  2
30 20  2  1
20 10  2  3
```

I'm not sure how to call in columns A and B as arguments for the function. I've tried `mutate_at(df, 3:4, funs(comp), c(df$A, df$B))`, but that returns:

```
 A  B C D
10  0 3 6
20 10 3 6
30 20 3 6
20 10 3 6
```

Doesn't have to be a tidyr solution, whatever works!
Thanks

Comment: Your function only takes two arguments. What should `x` and `y` be? `A` and `B`, or `A` & `C` and `B` & `C`, etc?

Comment: x is the number of interest, y is a vector of 2 numbers.
Ex. comp(13, c(10, 20)) returns 1, since that is the index of the closest number in the pair.
So for the df, c(df$A, df$B) is my attempt at calling the y argument, since the x argument should be an individual column (C or D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed around your function a little bit in order for vectorization to work. It also only accepted 2 values, when you were looking to compare 1 value with 2 others, so 3 arguments would be needed:

```
comp <- function(val, x, y){
  case_when(
    abs(val - x) < abs(val - y) ~ 1,
    abs(val - x) > abs(val - y) ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 3)
}

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(C,D), comp , .$A, .$B)

   A  B C D
1 10  0 1 1
2 20 10 1 2
3 30 20 2 1
4 20 10 2 3
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the introduction to `case_when`!